# How can I solve a fourth order system of PDEs?

Tags: differential-equations

My equations are:

$A_t=r A-\mu |A|^2A-\nu |B|^2A+(d/dx+\frac{e}{2i}(\partial^2/\partial_{xx}+\partial^2/\partial_{yy}))^2A$
$B_t=r B-\mu |B|^2B-\nu |A|^2B+(d/dy+\frac{e}{2i}(\partial^2/\partial_{xx}+\partial^2/\partial_{yy}))^2B$

where $r=40.0$, $\mu=2,\nu=1,e=0.1,i=\sqrt{-1}$

The initial conditions are:

$A_0=\sqrt{\frac{r-q^2(1+eq/2)^2}{\mu+\nu}}\exp(iqx)$

$B_0=\sqrt{\frac{r-q^2(1+eq/2)^2}{\mu+\nu}}\exp(iqy)$

The period condition is used here.

```
eq1 = 
  D[A[x, y, t], t] == 
    r A[x, y, t] - μ Abs[A[x, y, t]]^2 A[x, y, t] - 
    ν Abs[B[x, y, t]]^2 A[x, y, t] + D[A[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + 
    ϵ/I (D[A[x, y, t], {x, 3}] + D[D[A[x, y, t], {x, 1}], {y, 2}]) + 
    (ϵ/(2 I))^2 (D[A[x, y, t], {x, 4}] + D[A[x, y, t], {y, 4}]);

 eq2 = 
   D[B[x, y, t], t] == 
     r B[x, y, t] - μ Abs[B[x, y, t]]^2 B[x, y, t] - 
     ν Abs[A[x, y, t]]^2 B[x, y, t] + D[B[x, y, t], {y, 2}] + 
     ϵ/I (D[B[x, y, t], {y, 3}] + D[D[B[x, y, t], {y, 1}], {x, 2}]) + 
     (ϵ/(2 I))^2 (D[B[x, y, t], {x, 4}] + D[B[x, y, t], {y, 4}]);

q = -2; ϵ = 0.1; r = 40.0; μ = 2.0; ν = 1.0; L = 20;
R0 = Sqrt[(r - q^2 (1 + ϵ q/2)^2)/(μ + ν)];
As = R0 Exp[I q x]; Bs = R0 Exp[I q y]; 

sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {eq1, eq2, 
     A[x, y, 0] == As, B[x, y, 0] == Bs, 
     A[x, -L/2, t] == A[x, L/2, t], A[-L/2, y, t] == A[L/2, y, t], 
     B[x, -L/2, t] == B[x, L/2, t], B[-L/2, y, t] == B[L/2, y, t]}, 
    {A, B}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, 10}, 
    MaxSteps -> 10]
```

The code causes a kernel crash and I do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: "But is it wrong?" is too vague a question. Can you be specific and describe what is going wrong in detail?

Comment: @m_goldberg  It do not work, when I run the code, it quit the kernel

Comment: @yunshi Where did you get this system of equations?

Comment: The kernel also crashes with `\[Epsilon] = 0`, so the fourth derivatives are not at fault.  However, if initial conditions are set to `As = R0` and `Bs = R0` the kernel does not crash.  It may be that the kernel crashes, because the initial conditions do not satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  a paper from a  journal

Comment: @bbgodfrey the initial condition and pde are from a  paper  
ong wavelength instabilities of square patterns, Physica D 67 (1993) 198 223

Comment: @yunshi This system of equations describes some temperature pattern in 2D convection flow in square cavity in some approximation. It is good for analytical research, but not for numerical.  Nevertheless there are examples of numerical solution with pseudospectral method on a grid 100 by 100 in a paper sited.

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate numerical solution we need to put $L=2 n \pi, n=1, 2, ..., 15, ...$ (for example in [a paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/016727899390206G) $n=15$). This numerical solution with $n=1$ demonstrates zigzag instabilities

```
eq1 = D[A[x, y, t], t] == 
   r A[x, y, t] - \[Mu] Abs[A[x, y, t]]^2 A[x, y, 
      t] - \[Nu] Abs[B[x, y, t]]^2 A[x, y, t] + 
    D[A[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + \[Epsilon]/
      I (D[A[x, y, t], {x, 3}] + 
       D[D[A[x, y, t], {x, 1}], {y, 2}]) + (\[Epsilon]/(2 I))^2 (D[
        A[x, y, t], {x, 4}] + D[A[x, y, t], {y, 4}]);

eq2 = D[B[x, y, t], t] == 
   r B[x, y, t] - \[Mu] Abs[B[x, y, t]]^2 B[x, y, 
      t] - \[Nu] Abs[A[x, y, t]]^2 B[x, y, t] + 
    D[B[x, y, t], {y, 2}] + \[Epsilon]/
      I (D[B[x, y, t], {y, 3}] + 
       D[D[B[x, y, t], {y, 1}], {x, 2}]) + (\[Epsilon]/(2 I))^2 (D[
        B[x, y, t], {x, 4}] + D[B[x, y, t], {y, 4}]);

q = -2; \[Epsilon] = 0.1; r = 40.0; \[Mu] = 2.0; \[Nu] = 1.0; L = 2 Pi;
R0 = Sqrt[(r - q^2 (1 + \[Epsilon] q/2)^2)/(\[Mu] + \[Nu])];
As = R0 Exp[I q x]; Bs = R0 Exp[I q y];


{aS, bS} = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, A[x, y, 0] == As, B[x, y, 0] == Bs, 
   A[x, -L/2, t] == A[x, L/2, t], A[-L/2, y, t] == A[L/2, y, t], 
   B[x, -L/2, t] == B[x, L/2, t], B[-L/2, y, t] == B[L/2, y, t]}, {A, 
   B}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 80, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]

ContourPlot[
 Re[aS[x, y, 1] + bS[x, y, 1]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -L/2, L/2}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: Figure 1]